# Error Using Audio plugin

Tags: plugins, audio

I have installed the audio plugin, to create Xbrowser playlists, but I am getting the following error

`jPlayer 2.0.0 : id='jquery_jplayer_1' : Error!`

All I have done so far is create a new post, upload audio to the post using the wordpress audio uploader, added the playlist to the post using the following shortcode, and published.

```
[audio layout="list"]
```

and also tried

`[audio]`

but produced the same error

The files are .mp3 format, they play in other players fine.

The site is stored locally, in case that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own question. Kept here for others who may have in the same problem.

Turns out, being locally hosted WAS relevant. the problem is line 192 in `/wp-content/plugins/audio/js/audio.js`

`swfPath: 'http://' + window.location.host + '/wp-content/plugins/audio/js/',`

This expects the site to be based at the root `/`, as mine was in a folder I just changed it to:

`swfPath: 'http://' + window.location.host + 'MY_SITE/wp-content/plugins/audio/js/',`

and we're away.

**Remember:** revert to original line when moving to production.

Comment: This plugin should use some JS localization to pass things to the JS like site url and plugin url. Maybe you can tell the plugin author to make use of these functions then that way you wouldn't have to make this manual change. http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2010/05/07/adding-scripts-properly-to-wordpress-part-2-javascript-localization/